# Beginner in matlab : syntax to recup value of a line matrice

Tags: matlab, syntax

i'm beginner in MATLAB. My problem is :
When i want to take the value of the line in my matrice L(1x2) to stock it in the a and b variables, I tried to use the following code

```
[a,b]=L;
```

It didn't work well. I don't understand why it's not possible like this. I used this syntax for the line ginput(n). I used another method to take the value but I want to understand my error in the code above.
My final code is this :

```
clf();
n=10;
axis([0 10 0 10]);
[px,py] = ginput(n);
Y = py';
X = ones(1,n);
X=[X ; px'];
L= Y*pinv(X);
a = L(1,1);
b = L(1,2);
x = 0:0.2:10;
plot(x,b*x+a, px,py,'r+');
grid;
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot assign in MATLAB using

```
[a,b]=L
```

Instead, you can do the following:

```
L=[1,2];
L=num2cell(L);
[a,b]=deal(L{:});
```

Then `a=1` and `b=2`.